# Node.js Discord bot wait for roles to remove before proceeding

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot in Node.js where I make an API Call to fetch a person's ranks in a game, to then apply a rank role to that person in the server.

Before applying that role, I have to first remove all the current roles from that person, to then apply the new rank role.

Problem is that this is asynchronous, so I start removing all the roles and when I add the new role, it is still removing roles, causing the new role to get removed instantly.

I can't wrap my head around callbacks and promises, so I don't know how to proceed. Following is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < allranks.length; i++){
        var role = message.member.guild.roles.find('name', allranks[i]);
        message.member.removeRole(role).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

setTimeout(function(){
    var role = message.member.guild.roles.find('name', ranks[highestRank]);

    message.member.addRole(role).catch(err => console.log(err));

    message.reply("Rank updated to " + highestRank);

}, 2000)
```

As you can see, i'm setting a Timeout to wait for the rank removal to finish, before applying the new role. I know this is very bad and inefficient, so can someone help me out with either a callback or a promise?

Comment: I would recommend you use await/async - the code would be simple and much more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For carrying a series of promise , you should Promise.all

```
Promise.all(allranks.map(function(eachrank){
          var role = message.member.guild.roles.find('name',eachrank);
          return message.member.removeRole(role) ;   
    })).then(function(data){
          var role = message.member.guild.roles.find('name', ranks[highestRank]);
          return message.member.addRole(role)
    }).then(function(){
          return message.reply("Rank updated to " + highestRank)

    }).catch(function(err){
          console.log(err);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to work with async/await, it'll pay off.
With that you can do:

```
async function updateRank(member) {
    for(const i = 0; i < allranks.length; i++){
        const role = message.member.guild.roles.find('name', allranks[i]);
        await message.member.removeRole(role); //Notice the await.
    }

    const role = message.member.guild.roles.find('name', ranks[highestRank]);

    await message.member.addRole(role); //Notice the await here too.
    message.reply("Rank updated to " + highestRank);
}
```

The keyword `await` will make it so the code will wait until the promise is resolved (and also returns the promised object).
We don't need the object, we just want to wait.

I also changed some `var`s to `const`. I recommend using `let` and `const` too.

Comment: I tried this, but I get a SyntaxError: Unexpected token function. Am i missing something very obvious here?